# Facebook API: Error Creating Ad: Payment disabled for user (error_subcode: 1815010)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-business-sdk

We are having an issue with the Marketing API when trying to create Ads in Facebook.

The error we are getting is the following:

```
{
    "error":
    {
        "message":"Invalid parameter", 
        "type":"OAuthException",
        "code":100,
        "error_subcode":1815010,
        "is_transient":false,
        "error_user_title":"Payment disabled for the user",
        "error_user_msg":"Payment has been disabled for the user",
        "fbtrace_id":"A********s"
    }
}
```

This error only happens when I create `Ad`s.
We can correctly create: `Campaigns`, `AdSets` and `LeadForms` to all the accounts, but for certain accounts the `Ad` endpoint fails with that error.

The Accounts that fail and the ones that work correctly they have the same System User associated, and same payment method, under the same Business Manager and they promote the same Page.

Did anyone experience this? How did you solve it? Why does the same code call works for 1 account and not the other (same BM, Page, Payment Method and Users)